# Error while creating test user on Facebook "The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, roles

While creating a test user in my app in Facebook developer, I get this error:

> The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily

Is the issue from Facebook servers or the issue from my side?

Comment: Getting the same error right now.  Check their bug tracker for recent reports on this, and if there aren't any, create a new one. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Still having this issue. Wild. It has been a month already!

Comment: I need to create an access token to use Instagram API. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @ScottNimrod have you tried Graph API explorer by Facebook for this?

Comment: This question is closed because "not reproducible or was caused by typos", and was reviewed yesterday and left closed.  But as of this moment, it is still a problem.  I just reproduced it, and I did not make any typos.  Perhaps there is no "answer" that can be given, but the problem is real.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to a banner notice on [the official documentation page for "Test Users"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-users):

> We are temporarily removing the ability for apps to create new test users. This should not affect existing test users. We will share an update once access to creating new test users has been reinstated.

Comment: I'm observing the same issue a month later. Is this normal?

Comment: Normal for Facebook? Yeah. The community developer UX has been pretty poor over the years. Still, this is surprising because it prevents many of us from going through the App Review process, right?

Comment: The developer experience from Facebook is absolute trash. If you think this is bad, try going through Instagram app review. This is particularly frustrating, as others have noted, because test Facebook accounts are integral in passing review for both FB and IG. These accounts are also very useful in third party app reviewers in so far as they work as an easy way to "provision" test users in an SSO system, something that's basically impossible with Google, Apple, etc.

Comment: And here we are still experiencing the issue, does anyone has any update about it ?

Comment: June 1st 2023, still getting the same error.

Comment: July 29th and still the same.

Comment: Sep 22 and still the same

Comment: sep 24. still the same also

Comment: october 6, 2023, Still the same

Comment: October 10, 2023, still the same

Comment: Oct 19 still the same

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/595276292037723/ - This is one of the top voted unresolved issues. Upvoting and commenting on this issue might help bring more attention to it.

Comment: Oct 25 and still the same

Comment: Nov 11 still the same..... What a mess

Comment: lol so how to test the pages_read_engagement to read from posts?

Comment: Been nearly a year lol

Comment: Still the same!

Comment: Dec 27 2023 same sh*t

Comment: Jan 8, 2023 and still getting the same error

Comment: What is the alternative to this?

Comment: Jan 27, 2024 - Still same issue. Only alternative is to MANUALLY create a NEW facebook account using secondary credentials you control (secondary email, phone#), sign that new account up as a developer, then add them to the app as a "tester" role and use that new account as your "test" account for the review process.

Comment: @JosiahBryan are you able to solve that through the steps you mentioned, as I provided them with the app administrator account details but still they are saying that they are not able to test the app . not sure what kind of test user they need

Comment: Yes, since posting, I have been successfully verified through the review process! SO EXCITED, only took literally 10 times through the review process haha.

Comment: @rahularyansharma, in short, I had to:
1. Create a BRAND NEW facebook user, call it user "Bob"
2. I had to make Bob a Facebook Developer (sign Bob up for a developer profile)
3. I had to invite Bob to the **BUSINESS** that owned the bot that I'm trying to get approved - there I set Bob's role to "tester" and you can apply various limits on what Bob can access
4. I had to log back into Bob's account and "accept" the business invite
5. I had to add Bob to the **APP** as a "tester" role
6. Finally, in the App Review stuff, I had to explicitly tell them Bob's user/password for msging the bot

Comment: Feb 9, 2024 error still remains