# cant i add test-users to my facebook app anymore?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

i have created an app in facebook developer console in which i want to add test users to test my app and all api calls which is for content publishing and retrieving from instagram.

almost all api works but i want to test it from another user for that i am trying to add test-user to my app but it is not allowing me to add neigther from dashboard nor from api call.

when i try to add test user using api call (following endpoint i am trying to add test user)

[https://graph.facebook.com/1107166090678161/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Sarah_Johns&locale=en_US&permissions=email,instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights,pages_manage_ads,pages_manage_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,pages_read_user_content,public_profile,user_likes,user_posts,user_photos&access_token=1107166090678161|U7e3hIITj2U9JJir_nT-YRLcsMQ](https://graph.facebook.com/1107166090678161/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Sarah_Johns&locale=en_US&permissions=email,instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights,pages_manage_ads,pages_manage_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,pages_read_user_content,public_profile,user_likes,user_posts,user_photos&access_token=1107166090678161%7CU7e3hIITj2U9JJir_nT-YRLcsMQ)

and following response i am getting i mean the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO7hl.jpg)

i would appreciate any suggestion or guidance which has been provided.
thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating test user on Facebook "The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372025/error-while-creating-test-user-on-facebook-the-ability-to-create-test-users-is)

Answer (score -1):

On top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-users there's currently an alert displayed, reading

> We are temporarily removing the ability for apps to create new test users. This should not affect existing test users. We will share an update once access to creating new test users has been reinstated.

So the error message you are getting is very likely to be related to this.

Comment: yes sir i read that but my concern was how do i test my app with some other user than admin

Comment: If you want to test with real user accounts - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles#tester