# Unable to create test user in Facebook development account for testing

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to set up test users for my app, but I keep getting the 'The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily' message. Has anyone found a workaround for this or received any updates from Facebook regarding when this feature will be back?

I tried multiple times, but it seems to be working now.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-users: _"We are temporarily removing the ability for apps to create new test users. This should not affect existing test users. We will share an update once access to creating new test users has been reinstated."_

Comment: I have also checked this one. but it won't work.

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what this note is trying to tell you - this is currently disabled, you _can not_ create new test users right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating test user on Facebook "The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372025/error-while-creating-test-user-on-facebook-the-ability-to-create-test-users-is)

Answer (score 0):

This warning is now visible. As a result, I am awaiting an update.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in need of test users, this is a solution that worked for me when trying to get an Instagram app validated by the FB review team:

- Create an Instagram user or use some test account you may already have
- Set up 2FA
- Once set, get the recovery codes (something like XXXX XXXX)
- When you send your account for validation, include the account username, password and at least one of the recovery codes, so the reviewer can access the account and test it.